# Modify b-card title using CSS bootstrap-vue

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

So I have the following code:

```
<b-card
  class="getting-started border-0"
  overlay
  img-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554386690-cc2d52c7f3d6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1395&q=80"
  img-alt="Card Image"
  text-variant="white"
  title="Getting Started"
  sub-title="Where to begin?"
>
    <b-card-text>
          Some quick example text to build on the card and make up the bulk of the card's content.
    </b-card-text>
</b-card>
```

I would like to sytle the title inside b-card utilizing css. I haven't been able to find any  way to access this element.

Comment: Style it how? And what have you tried so far yourself? Please add the styling code that doesn't work. Please read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a custom class to b-card and then you need to write a simple css.

**HTML**

```
<b-card class="my-custom-class border-0"
  overlay
  img-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554386690-cc2d52c7f3d6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1395&q=80"
  img-alt="Card Image"
  text-variant="white"
  title="Getting Started"
  sub-title="Where to begin?"
>
<b-card-text>
  Some quick example text to build on the card and make up the bulk of the card's content.
</b-card-text>
</b-card>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-custom-class .card-title {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! this will be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

`title = ""`   Doesn't apply to `CSS`

use
`v-bind:title="nameTitle"`for dynamic change `title`

or

It is often a good idea to bind to a style object

`<div v-bind:style="styleObject"></div>`

```js
data: {
  styleObject: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '13px'
  }
}
```

The object syntax is often used in conjunction with computed properties that return objects.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for the help I am kinda new to front-end but this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

CSS classes. You can put the element in a CSS class, then apply the desired styles on the class.

```
<b-card class="getting-started border-0"
  overlay
  img-src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554386690-cc2d52c7f3d6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1395&q=80"
  img-alt="Card Image"
  text-variant="white"
  title="Getting Started"
  sub-title="Where to begin?"
>
<b-card-text class="red-sample">
  Some quick example text to build on the card and make up the bulk of the card's content.
</b-card-text>
</b-card>

...

<style>
.red-sample {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The item that I want to access it's b-card title="Getting Started". Sorry for not clarifying that in question, can I add a css selector for that title